# alert message does not appear

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=document.f1.tt1.value;
alert(x);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" name="tt" value="jawadi" />
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**the alert message does not appear , what is the problem?
thanks for your help :) :)
**

Comment: `document.f1` is not yet defined when the script is executed as it appears after the `<script>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your script is you are trying to get the value of element which has not been created in the DOM yet. So you are getting the null value because it does not exist. One thing you can do is include the script at the bottom of the page so that it gets the value

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <form name="f1">
    <input type="text" name="tt" value="jawadi" />
    </form>
    </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var x=document.f1.tt.value;//the name of textbox is tt
       alert(x);
    </script>
    </html>
```

Second thing that you can try if you are comfortable with jquery is use .ready function, so it will get the value after page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var x=document.f1.tt.value;//the name of textbox is tt
           alert(x);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers your document may not be ready. 
In your script tag have:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var x = document.f1.tt.value;
    })
```

A nicer way might be to give your input an id.

```
<input type="text" name="tt" id="myInput" value="jawadi" />
$(document).ready(function(){
     var x = $("#myInput").val();    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" name="tt" value="jawadi" />
</form>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=document.f1.tt.value;
alert(x);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

because javacript not found f1 try this

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var x=document.f1.tt1.value;
```

with

```
var x=document.f1.tt.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified code:  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VkjyA/)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function alertX(){
       var x=document.f1.tt.value;
       alert(x);
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body  onload='alertX();'><!-- call alertX on body load-->
    <form name="f1">
        <input type="text" name="tt" value="jawadi" />
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```